# Sorting by columns in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, file-handling

I have a file named all_energy.out and I am trying to sort it in a way so I can renumber files in the directory based on the lowest energy in the all_energy.out file. So I want to create an array with the file names and energy starting at the lowest energy and going to increasing energy like name and age.

Analogous Example:

```
Don 24
Jan 30
Sue 19
```

sorted to

```
Sue 19
Don 24
Jan 30
```

Example of all_energy.out file: The highest negative value is the lowest energy.

```
                                  Energy
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0001  -219.209742 
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0002  -219.188106
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0003  -219.064542
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0004  -219.050730
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0005  -219.044573
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0006  -218.927479
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0007  -218.919717
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0008  -218.900923
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0009  -218.898945
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0010  -218.889269
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0011  -218.871619
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0012  -218.859429
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0013  -218.848516
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0014  -218.835355
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0015  -218.822244
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0016  -218.819328
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0017  -218.818431
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0018  -218.815494
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0019  -218.798388
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0020  -218.792151
                                  Energy
0002_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0001  -226.007998
0002_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0002  -225.635657
```

The file names are given before the energy value, for example 0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0001.mol2 is the name of the first file.

Example solution:

```
0002_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0001  -226.007998
0002_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0002  -225.635657
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0001  -219.209742
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0002  -219.188106
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0003  -219.064542
```

My current script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Name of all total energy containing file:\n";
my $energy_file = <STDIN>;
chomp $energy_file;

my $inputfile_energy = $energy_file;

open (INPUTFILE_ENERGY, "<", $inputfile_energy) or die $!;

print map $inputfile_energy->[0],
sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
map { [ $_, /(\d+)$/ ] }
<INPUTFILE_ENERGY>;

close $inputfile_energy;
```

At this point I am just trying to get the energy with their names to print to the correct order. Then I will loop through the files in the directory and when the name matches with the sorted energy names it will be renumber.

Comment: Sorry, still having a hard time grasping what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Does the example solution help?

Comment: Nothing coherent prints is the problem... I will keep that in mind though!

Answer (score 2):

Problems with your script:

1. `/(\d+)$/` only matches digits (0-9) at the end of a line. Your file contains floating point numbers, so only digits after the decimal point will be matched. You could get away with `/(\S+)$/` instead. (Actually, in your sample input there is a line with a trailing space, so let's make that `/(\S+)\s*$/` instead)
2. `$inputfile_energy` is a filename, a scalar, and not a reference, so `$inputfile_energy->[0]` doesn't make sense. You use it as the expression in a `map` construction, and in a `map EXPR, LIST` construction, `$_` refers to the current element of the list that is being iterated through, so you probably just meant to say `$_->[0]`.
3. Your input contains a few lines -- all with the keyword `Energy` -- that don't have the same format as the other lines you want to sort and should be filtered out.

Putting this all together, I get working code when the penultimate statement looks like:

```
print map $_->[0],
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
    map { [ $_, /(\S+)\s*$/ ] }
    grep /\d/,
        <INPUTFILE_ENERGY>;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use oneliner like this and run it from command line:

```
perl -lnae 'push @arr, [$_, $F[1]] if $F[1]; END { print join "\n", map {$_->[0]} sort {$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]} @arr }' energy_file.txt
```

1) special key `-n` makes the loop over all lines in input file (energy_file.txt); current line is available in $_ variable.

2) then key `-a` splits each line by whitespaces and puts nonempty values into @F array.

Answer (score 1):

A less "idiomatic" solution could be :

```
@data = <DATA>;
my @table;

foreach(@data){
    chomp;
    next unless /^0/;     # skip Energy lines (or any other cleaning test)     
    @line = split /\s+/;
    push @table,[@line];  # build a 2d array
}

my @sortedTable = sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @table;

foreach(@sortedTable){
    printf(
        "%5s,%25s\n",
        $_->[0],
        $_->[1]
        ) # some pretty printing
}


__DATA__
                                  Energy
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0001  -219.209742 
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0002  -219.188106
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0003  -219.064542
0001_IP3_fullBinding_Rigid0004  -219.050730
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print join "\n", sort {(split /\s+/,$a)[1] <=> (split /\s+/,$b)[1]} map{chomp $_; $_} <INPUTFILE_ENERGY>;
```

Comment: As a code only answer, I think this really would benefit from a little more explanation.